# Zurb Foundation Sticky Footer

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, sticky-footer

I want to have sticky footer using Foundation 4, and I want to use HTML5 `<footer>` tag, not `<div class="footer">`. Also I just don't want to change the foundation.css, not to break it other parts of the framework. I tried http://tangerineindustries.com/download/sticky_footer/ but it doesn't work on Chrome and IE 10. Any suggestion how to achieve it, either css only or js? Is it possible to do it only changing app.css and/or app.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This post explains my favorite method, using CSS only. Works in all major browsers, including IE5 and up (I only test down to IE8 though):
http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

And I use it together with Foundation 4.

If you happen to be using Compass, they have a mixin that uses this same method:
http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/layout/sticky_footer/

Comment: Are you putting the css code there into app.css directly? No modification to foundation.css?

Comment: You want to add this in wherever your own css styles are (which yes, may be app.css/scss). Don't modify foundation.css. And make sure to include app.css after foundation.css.